# How to set text for a MenuItem inside a for loop?

Tags: java, javafx

I am creating a JavaFX program. Iwas trying to create menu items with a for loop.
I have tried to set text to MenuItem by placing the variable to the parameter. **Error = int cannot be converted to String.**

```
 MenuButton mes = new MenuButton("Mês");
        for(int i=1; i<=10; i++){
            mes.getItems().add(new MenuItem(i));
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

From the source code,

```
public MenuItem(String label) throws HeadlessException {
    this(label, null);
}
```

So, to construct an object of `MenuItem` you need to pass in a `String` as a label.

You'll need to change your code to

```
mes.getItems().add(new MenuItem(String.valueOf(i)));
```

to convert `i` to a String for calling the constructor.